# jQuery hover strange bug

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-hover

I have little problem with my jQuery hover. I make my personal page and I load my data from AJAX. So I cant figure out why the hover is bugging. First I tough it was because my element was with position:absolute, but then i edited it and made it normal div.Here is my code:

```
<td id="project" style="background: url('img/pctutorials-bg.png');background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:center center;vertical-align:bottom;" >
<div class="projectinfo" >
<div class="text" >PCTutorials-BG</div>
</div>
</td>
```

jQuery

```
$(".projectinfo").hover(
  function () {
    alert("Inside");
  },
  function () {
    alert("Outside");
  }
);
```

Can this because this is on element that is not on the page when the page loads. I load the element later with AJAX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` functionality on all current and future elements like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('#project').on('mouseenter', '.projectinfo', function () {
    alert("Inside");
  }).on('mouseleave', '.projectinfo', function () {
    alert("Outside");
  });
);
```

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/on/

`hover` is equivalent to `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`, so `hover` cannot be directly used with `on`. It's a little heavy to add both functionalities to hover, so it's preferred to use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` separately.

The reason I use `$('#project').on` is for performance. jQuery has to search the *entire* DOM tree looking for `.projectinfo` nodes every time you create something, so this will make jQuery only look under `#project` instead. Much faster.

Answer (score 1):

Then you need to try this:

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.projectinfo', function () {
    alert("Inside");
}).on('mouseleave', '.projectinfo', function () {
    alert("Outside");
});
```

Comment: Handlers are attached to the currently selected elements in the jQuery object, so those elements must exist at the point the call to .bind() occurs.